# Lubuntu 12.04 wireless not working

Tags: wireless, networking, lubuntu

I am using an Lubuntu 12.04 with a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop.

Everything works fine except the wireless connection doesn't work.
If I plug the cable in it works right away but I can't get the wireless to connect.

I have the network manager open, and it detects the networks around, but when I click a given network, one without a password, the tray icon for the network manager just display an arrow going continuously in circles forever.

It's like the wireless is working but that there is just some tiny thing somewhere blocking. And I get no error or anything.

What can I do to get the wireless working?

Comment: Can you tell us what wireless hardware you have?

Comment: Please include this information in the body of your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now five days later the wireless works without problems.
I didn't change anything and I have no idea why the system behaves this way.

I recommend storing this question just as documentation.

Comment: I suggest that you remove your ESSID and/or your access point from your post above. Having both publicly is not that safe ;)

Answer (score 1):

i would try iwconfig to see whats going on

Comment: question updated.

Comment: ok sry, but now we know that is interface is detected